# Programmatically focus and select value in react-select

Tags: reactjs, styled-components, react-select, ref

I want to be able to programmatically `focus()` and `select()` a `react-select`. Clicking on `Add new brand` below:

[image]

should render something like this:

[image]

Here's what I have so far.

My `Select` component is wrapped in `React.forwardRef`:

```
const Select = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  return (
    <Creatable ref={ref} {...props} />
  )
})
```

so that I can style it with `styled-components` and still have a `ref` to its input, like so:

```
const BrandSelect = styled(Select)`...`
const Button = styled.button`...`

const MyComponent = () => {

  const brandSelectRef = useRef()
  const [newBrand, setNewBrand] = useState(false)

  const handleAddBrand = () => {
    setNewBrand(true)
    console.log(brandSelectRef.current)
    if (brandSelectRef && brandSelectRef.current) {
      brandSelectRef.current.focus()
      brandSelectRef.current.select()
    }
  }

  return (
    <BrandSelect
      creatable
      openMenuOnFocus
      ref={brandSelectRef}
      defaultInputValue={newBrand ? '...' : undefined}
      // ...other required react-select props
    />
    <Button onClick={handleAddBrand}>Add new brand</Button>
  )
}
```

The problem is, though, that the above code doesn't work, i.e. `react-select` never gets focused. Also, the log `brandSelectRef.current` is `undefined`.

I'm clearly doing something wrong here, but I can't spot what.

Answer (score 2):

I think the cause is that you have to use default value for your `useRef` hook

```
const brandSelectRef = useRef(null)
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but it doesn't seem to be it... Now my `console.log` returns `null`.

Comment: @artooras I made an example for you https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-tereshkova-1v6t2?file=/src/App.js . I hope it will help you

Comment: Thanks! Really helpful. If you try, however, your example works even if using `useRef()` without a value. In my case, however, a Select is wrapped in a `styled-component`, which may be the reason for why I'm facing issues...

Answer (score -1):

Use this construction:

```
const inputRef = useRef();

      useEffect(() => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          inputRef.current.select();
        }, 0);
      }, []);
```